# Connect to sql server with management studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, remote-access, remote-server

I have a sql server hosted on go daddy that I simply am unable to connect to using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express or Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Cannot connect to RBSAssetTracker.db.2574383.hostedresource.com.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 67)

Am I missing something? This seems like it should be relatively simple to accomplish this.

Comment: Update to question, I was able to establish a connection using another  machine in a different locatiopn. Not sure if this is pertinent but its a virtual machine that I am attempting to access the server from thats causing the error.

Comment: I guess there is no network connectivity from the virtual machine. Did you connect using named pipes from the other machine? Use PING and TELNET to identify where you are losing network connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

first check whether you can ping the database server then check following

Step 1) Make sure SQL SERVER is up and the instance you try to connect is running.
Step 2) Your system Firewall should not block SQL Server port.
Step 3) Go to Computer Management >> Service and Application >> SQL Server 2005 Configuration >> Network Configuration
Enable TCP/IP protocol. Make sure that SQL SERVER port is by Default 1433.
Step 4) Now follow this KB Article of MSDN depending on your server :
 http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277

Answer (score 0):

open your godaddy account, 
click launch under your webhosting menu, 
click on SQL server database
click actions-->details and watch for the 'hostname' 
it will be like : databasename.db.99999999.hostedresource.com
copy and paste that thing to 'Server name' while logging to your management studio
Enter your godaddy sql-server database username and password to login in management studio. It should work right.